# Stack on working as expected | z-index (CSS) equivalent

Tags: flutter

I am trying to achieve this(Todo image) but the image is getting hidden. How to bring it on top? I thought using Stack will automatically bring it on top. Is there any z-index equivalent? I have also shared the code below

## Todo

[image]

## In Progress

[image]

## Code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        new SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 150.0,
          flexibleSpace: new FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: new Stack(
              alignment: new Alignment(0.0, 2.5),
              children: [
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new AssetImage("images/Theme-pattern.png"))),
                  child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
                    new Text("Title", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0)),
                  ]),
                ),
                new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(120.0)),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  width: 100.0,
                  child: new Image.asset("images/photo.png"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Stack will automatically bring it on top"? The order you add the widgets to the array defines which one is on top of others or below.

Answer (score 18):

You can definitely use Stack. Check this below code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final double topWidgetHeight = 200.0;
  final double avatarRadius = 50.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                height: topWidgetHeight,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              new Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              )
            ],
          ),
          new Positioned(
            child: new CircleAvatar(
              radius: avatarRadius,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            ),
            left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2) - avatarRadius,
            top: topWidgetHeight - avatarRadius,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I got it, but I don’t want to get rid of the custom scroll view and silvers. That shrinks (animates) the appBar while scrolling. I tried moving the stack up one level like you did but it didn’t work. Is there any other way

Comment: This is the effect it gives. Refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/48121864/2619454

Answer (score 12):

Just add **clipBehavior: Clip.none**  to Stack widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        new SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 150.0,
          flexibleSpace: new FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: new Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              alignment: new Alignment(0.0, 2.5),
              children: [
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          image: new AssetImage("images/Theme-pattern.png"))),
                  child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
                    new Text("Title", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0)),
                  ]),
                ),
                new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(120.0)),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  width: 100.0,
                  child: new Image.asset("images/photo.png"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this package https://pub.dev/packages/indexed

[example image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/physia/kflutter/main/indexed/doc/assets/demo.gif)

This package allows  you to order items inside stack using `index` like `z-index` in CSS.

easily you can change the order of items by change the `index` property
this is example how it works

```
Indexer(
    children: [
        Indexed(
          index: 100,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
        Indexed(
          index: 1000,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
        Indexed(
          index: 3,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
    ],
);
```

if you are using bloc of some complex widget you can extend or implement the `IndexedInterface` class and override `index` getter:

```
class IndexedDemo extends IndexedInterface {
    int index = 5;
}
```

or implements

```
class IndexedDemo extends AnimatedWidget implements IndexedInterface {
    int index = 1000;
    //...

    //...
}
```

then use it just like `Indexed` class widget:

```
Indexer(
    children: [
        IndexedDemo(
          index: 100,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
        IndexedFoo(
          index: 1000,
          child: Positioned(
            //...
          )
        ),
    ],
);
```

Online [demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2bbadcf3554cf5d7222b62c639a18e5d&null_safety=true)
Video [demo](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22839194/131275765-9f1c037c-b4c5-4dfe-877f-14d5ee3f16e5.mp4)